# Find an element of the array in an efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples

So I have a numpy array (b) that looks like this:

```
  [[1, 2, 20.1, 20.0],
  [1, 4, 22.1, 21.0],
  [1, 9, 25.1, 20.0],
  [1, 12, 27.1, 22.0]]
```

Basically the first two numbers (1,2) (1,4) (1,9) (1,12) represent x and y. 
The other two (20.1, 20.00) represent two other quantities.

I would like to access the array in a way that:

```
b[1,2,0] = 20.1
b[1,2,1] = 20.0   
b[1,4,0] = 22.1  
b[1,4,1] = 21.0
```

As far as I know, there is the possibility to use structured arrays. But, is there another way to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? What are 1, 2, 0 in the first index?

Comment: For example, are the two additional numbers tied respectively to x and y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert your array (which uses subscript-style indexing) to a dictionary (which uses 3-tuple-style indexing):

```
a = {}
for i in range(len(b)):
    a[b[i][0], b[i][1], 0] = b[i][2]
    a[b[i][0], b[i][1], 1] = b[i][3]
```

The dictionary you want will be in `a`

EDIT: I am assuming that `b[1, 2, 1]` should be `20.0` and not `20.9`

Comment: This works. Thanks! The only way to do it is with dictionaries? Because I need to do operations with arrays with big dimensions like 2000^3. And as far as I know, looping dictionaries won't be as fast as looping numpy arrays.

Comment: @FF10: The problem with using an array is that your data is sparse. What should `data[1, 3, 0]` be? How about `data[1, 5, 0]`? Neither of those is defined by your example dataset, but an array needs to have something in all of its places normally (certainly it does for the efficient math operations).

Comment: @Blckknght Ok, I understand the problem. But with dictionaries, I don't need to do loops to find where the position x=1 and x= 2 is located in the array b. This is going to save me a lot of time, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Other option using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by conditional indexing.
Just defines a method that directly access the array:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[1, 2, 20.1, 20.0],
             [1, 4, 22.1, 21.0],
             [1, 9, 25.1, 20.0],
             [1, 12, 27.1, 22.0]])

def pick_up(h, k, i=0):
  return b[np.where( (b[:,0] == h) & (b[:,1] == k) )][0,i+2]

pick_up(1, 9, 0) #=> 25.1
pick_up(1, 12, 1) #=> 22.0
```

Answer (score 0):

***Setup***

```
a = np.array([[ 1. ,  2. , 20.1, 20. ],
              [ 1. ,  4. , 22.1, 21. ],
              [ 1. ,  9. , 25.1, 20. ],
              [ 1. , 12. , 27.1, 22. ]])
```

---

This is a fairly standard numpy operation.  If your input array gets very large, I'd recommend looking into a `scipy` sparse matrix, but for your use case, using an array is completely fine.  The general idea is to create an array of shape `(maxx, maxy, 2)`, and use numpy assignment to fill:

```
s = a[:, :2].astype(int)
x, y = s.T
m, n = s.max(0) + 1
z = np.zeros((m, n, 2))
z[x, y] = a[:, 2:]
```

Now simply access `z` the way you desire:

```
>>> z[1, 2, 0]
20.1
```